# JQuery Select a Child Element within Previous Closest Element

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML like this:

```
<article>
  <aside>
    <p class="target-goal">This is my goal to target, which is initially hidden.</p>
  </aside>
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <time>5:00</time>
  </header>
  <a href="somewhere.php" class="toggle">Show Target</a>
</article>
```

I'm trying to make it so when you click on `.toggle` I can show `p.target-goal`.

Here's the jQuery I've been trying, along with several variations using closest, etc.:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).prev('aside').children('.target-goal').slideToggle();
});
```

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).parents('article').find('.target-goal').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('article').find('aside').find('.target-goal').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('article').find('.target-goal').slideToggle();
});
```

Your way was failing because of [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) which looks at the immediate previous sibling, which in your case is a header element. You could however, have done `.prev().prev()`, but I'd recommend `.closest()` instead.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qZpv5/)**

Answer (score 0):

`.prev` select the very previous element, hence it select the `header` and since you pass an argument (`aside`) and they don't match, it return nothing.

You can use siblings :

```
$(this).siblings('aside').children('.target-goal').slideToggle();
```

or prevAll :

```
$(this).prevAll('aside').children('.target-goal').slideToggle();
```

or closest / find :

```
$(this).closest('article').find('.target-goal').slideToggle();
```